# Compare input number to a value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I made a program to manage a dogpound (kennel, in swedish).
I give it the possibility to add a dog, list every dog with a tail length longer or equal then the given length, remove a dog or stop the program.
I have problems when I have to list all the dogs looking for their tail length.
The method in my program is called `listaHundarna()` and I ask the minimum tail length to search for. The if-statement gives me an error that I'm not able to solve.

can somebody help me please?

The first class is the dog (`Hund`) and the second is the dog pound class(`Kennel`).

Hund:

```
public class Hund {

    private String HundNamn;
    private String HundRas;
    private int HundÅlder;
    private double HundVikt;
    private double HundSvansLängd;
    private String tax = "tax";

    Hund(String namn, String ras, int ålder, double vikt, double svans){ //Skapa hundmetod som tar emot datan från super/main-klassen (Kennel.java);
    HundNamn = namn;
    HundRas = ras;
    HundÅlder = ålder;
    HundVikt = vikt;
    HundSvansLängd = svans;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return HundNamn+" "+HundRas+" "+HundÅlder+" years old "+HundVikt+" kg "+"tail lenght= "+HundSvansLängd;
        }

    public String getNamn() {
        return HundNamn;
        }


}
```

Kennel:

```
public class Kennel {

static ArrayList<Hund> HundLista= new ArrayList<Hund>();
private static Scanner tangentbord = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int val(String tal) {
        System.out.print(tal);
        return tangentbord.nextInt();
    }


    private static void kör() {
        for (;;) {
            Meny();
            switch (välja()) {
            case 1:
                läggTillHund();
                break;
            case 2:
                listaHundarna();
                break;
            case 3:
                taBortHund();
                break;
            case 4:
                avsluta();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Meny() {
        System.out.println("Tryck 1 för att lägga till en hund");
        System.out.println("Tryck 2 för att lista hundarna");
        System.out.println("Tryck 3 för att ta bort en hund");
        System.out.println("Tryck 4 för att avsluta programmet");   
    }

    private static int välja() {
        return val("> ");
    }

    public static void läggTillHund(){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Hundens namn:");
        String namn = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hundens ras: ");
        String ras = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hundens ålder: ");
        int ålder=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Hundens vikt: ");
        double vikt=sc.nextDouble();
        String tax = "tax";
        double svans;
        if (ras.equals(tax)) { 
            svans = 3.7;
            }
            else {
                svans = (ålder*vikt)/10;
            }
        System.out.println("Hundens svans är "+svans+"cm lång");
        Hund nyhund = new Hund(namn, ras, ålder, vikt, svans);
        HundLista.add(nyhund);  
    }


    public static void listaHundarna(){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ange svanslängd:");
        double minstasvanslängd=sc.nextDouble();
        int h=0;
        while(h<HundLista.size()){
            if(HundLista.get(h)>minstasvanslängd){
                System.out.println(HundLista.get(h));
        }
        }
    }

    public static void taBortHund(){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ange hundens namn:");
        String radera= sc.nextLine();
        for(int x=0;x<HundLista.size();x++){
            if (HundLista.get(x).equals(radera)){
                HundLista.remove(x);
                System.out.println("Hunden har tagits bort");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Hundens namn är inte korrekt");
            }


        }
    }

    public static void avsluta(){
    System.out.println("Programmet avslutas");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    kör();
    avsluta();
    }

}
```

Comment: And what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(HundLista.get(h)>minstasvanslängd){
```

HundLista.get(h) returns a Hund object and minstasvanslängd is a double, you can't use the primitive operator ">" to compare an Object and a primitive.
The if condition should be

```
if(HundLista.get(h).HundSvansLängd>minstasvanslängd){
```

assuming HundSvansLängd is public.

Comment: thanks i wrote that and it partially solved the problem. what i get now is that assuming that i'm adding 2 dogs and the first one has a tail 3 cm long and the second one 5 cm long when i search for the dogs with a tail at least 2 cm long the result is an infinite loop of a list containing the informations only about the first dog that i've added...what did i do wrong?

Comment: That's because "h" isn't changing, it's staying equal to zero. Change your code to be                                                     `while(h++<HundLista.size()){
    if(HundLista.get(h)>minstasvanslängd){          System.out.println(HundLista.get(h));`

Comment: ok thank you very much i solve it! can i ask you something else? i changed the remove a dog(taborthund) method with this code( public static void taBortHund(){
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Ange hundens namn:");
  String radera= sc.nextLine();
  int x=0;
  while(x<HundLista.size()){
   if(HundLista.get(x).equals(radera)){
    HundLista.remove(x);
   }
   else{
    x++;
   }
  }
  System.out.println(HundLista);
 }
but it does not remove the dog i select. what have i done wrong?

Comment: The equals method isn't doing what you think it is. That equals method comes from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html and is only comparing the memory addresses of the two objects, you need to override it in your Hund class like so `public boolean equals(Object obj) {boolean result = false; if (obj instanceof Hund) {Hund hund = (Hund) obj; result = hund.getNamn().equals(getNamn());} return result;}`

Comment: Hi i'm sorry but i have another problem but i cannot ask a new question due to the limit that i've already reached. in the Kennel class i have a method to remove a dog (taborthund). i forgot that i have to print a message that the dog name han not been found in case there's no dog with the name that the user digits. how do i get this message only once(when all the dogs names in the array has been checked) and not after every dog name it checks? thanks

Comment: `public static void taBortHund() {
  boolean hundExisterar = true;
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Ange hundens namn:");
  String radera= sc.nextLine();
  for(int x=0;x<HundLista.size();x++){
   if (HundLista.get(x).equals(radera)){
    HundLista.remove(x);
    System.out.println("Hunden har tagits bort");
   }
   else{
    hundExisterar = false;
   }
  }
  
  if(!hundExisterar) {
   System.out.println("Hundens namn är inte korrekt");
  } 
 }`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a Hund object to a double variable :

```
if(HundLista.get(h)>minstasvanslängd){
```

You should compare the relevant property of the Hund object to `minstasvanslängd`.

```
if(HundLista.get(h).getTailLength()>minstasvanslängd){
```

where `getTailLength()` should be replaced with a method that returns the tail length of the dog.

Comment: and what should i write instead?

Comment: thanks i wrote that and it partially solved the problem. what i get now is that assuming that i'm adding 2 dogs and the first one has a tail 3 cm long and the second one 5 cm long when i search for the dogs with a tail at least 2 cm long the result is an infinite loop of a list containing the informations only about the first dog that i've added...what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(HundLista.get(h)>minstasvanslängd)
```

Here you try to compare an object of type `Hund` to a `double`. This should be

```
if(HundLista.get(h).getSvansLängd() > minstasvanslängd)
```

provided that you add a getter `getSvansLängd()` in the `Hund` class like this:

```
public class Hund {

    private String HundNamn;
    private String HundRas;
    private int HundÅlder;
    private double HundVikt;
    private double HundSvansLängd;
    private String tax = "tax";

    Hund(String namn, String ras, int ålder, double vikt, double svans){ //Skapa hundmetod som tar emot datan från super/main-klassen (Kennel.java);
    HundNamn = namn;
    HundRas = ras;
    HundÅlder = ålder;
    HundVikt = vikt;
    HundSvansLängd = svans;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return HundNamn+" "+HundRas+" "+HundÅlder+" years old "+HundVikt+" kg "+"tail lenght= "+HundSvansLängd;
        }

    public String getNamn() {
        return HundNamn;
        }

    public double getSvansLängd() {
        return HundSvansLängd;
    }
}
```